# Environmental issues do matter

Tags: grammar, emphasis

I have written the following statement which a friend says is wrong for including the word *do.* Would anyone explain?

> Environmental issues do matter.

I wanted to say that people have to consider the environmental impacts seriously during plant's operations and do their best to protect the environment.

Just to convince them to not underestimate the potential of harming the environment and to tell them this is big deal to us.

Comment: Why do you think it's wrong?

Comment: Please add more information to your question. Why did you write it? Is it part of a paragraph? If so, show us more. Why do you think it's wrong? The sentence can be right or wrong, depending on what you want to say.

Comment: You've told us what you've wanted to say, but you still haven't said anything about why you think it's wrong.

Comment: To be honest my friend told me it is wrong and you have to remove "do" from the sentence.

Comment: The use of 'do' is absolutely correct.

Comment: If you can tell us why you used the sentence, we can give you a useful answer. For example, we would more likely use *do* if we want to disagree with a previous statement that the environment doesn't matter. Your reason about your friend is fine. Edit your question to improve it.

Comment: I think there is now a suffiently detailed question. An answer might briefly explain when speakers would more likely make one choice over the other. The OP has been responsive here.

Answer (score 3):

The sentence is ok, but there is a difference between

> Environmental issues matter.

and

> Environmental issues do matter.

The first sentence is the more simple way to make the statement, and we would normally choose this way unless we want to make a contrast with something said or implied earlier.

We might choose the second way to give the statement emphasis, especially if we want to rebut or contradict an earlier statement or assumption. For example:

Susan: *Environmental issues don't matter.*

Shayqi: *Environmental issues do matter.*

We can see this emphasizing or contrasting function at work with a similar pair of sentences:

> She hit me.
>
> She did hit me.

Both sentences are ok, but we may use them differently.

A father saw his son crying and asked his daughter:

*Did you hit Johnny?*

*No I didn't hit him,* she said.

Johnny then yelled, *She did hit me!*

However, if nothing has been said before, it would not be normal to just tell someone *She did hit me.*

To give you advice about which one to use in your situation, we would need to know more about what was written or said previously, and what meaning you want to give.

Comment: Thanks jim. I just wanted to use "do" to  emphasis the sentence and nothing have been said before to contradict with this sentence.

Comment: If we just use the sentence with *do," it can be like saying "Environmental issues really are important." But it can be tricky to use it effectively, depending on where, when, and how we use it. I am not able to explain this in detail unless I spent a long time thinking. And I am not good at thinking. :D